# Trying to upload app and validation for bundle identifier is failing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Itunes store operation failed. No suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct.

This error comes up when I try to validate my app in the organizer. My understanding is that it's because they're not the same name in the bundle ID and on the itunes connect page. I've made them both the same name in each bundle ID but it still comes up. What i've noticed though is the "application-identifier" hasn't been changed yet even though i've renamed the bundle ID. Is there somewhere else I have to change the name so that it syncs up with the other 2 bundle ID's and I don't get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I had to rename either the Executable file, the bundle display name, or the bundle name in the info section.